# Method for SQLalchemy selectable in pandas read_sql

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, pandas, sqlalchemy

trying to get results from a sqlalchemy query:

```
l = session.query(a.id)
```

this works for the correct result:

```
df = pd.read_sql(sql=l.statement,con=conn)
```

additionally, this will return the correct sql:

```
print(l)
```

however, the documentation indicates that using pandas.read_sql:

```
df = pd.read_sql(l, conn)
```

should return the results, correct?

reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`session.query()` produces a query object. See [sqlalchemy.org](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html)

`pd.read_sql(sql, con)` requires select or text object. From your reference:

> sql : string or SQLAlchemy Selectable (select or text object) SQL
>   query to be executed or a table name.

You can check type of `l` and `l.statement`:

`type(l)` 'sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query'

`type(l.statement)`
'sqlalchemy.sql.annotation.AnnotatedSelect'

When you do print(query), query class is defined to return select statement.